# Взять длину length коллекции после работы директивы ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Здравствуйте! Вот такая вот заминка получается, директива ng-repeat выводит в список

```
angular.module("NameApp").controller("MainController", ['$scope', '$http', 'httpService',
  function MainController($scope, $http, httpService) {
    $http.post('model/get_images.php').then(function(response) {
      $scope.images = response.data;
    });

  }
]);
```

Вот директива

```
angular.module('HelpApp').directive('sliderShow', function sliderShow() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: "<ul id='ul'><li ng-repeat='img in images'><img ng-src='img/{{img.src}}' alt='{{img.title}}'></li></ul>",
    link: function link(scope, element, attr) {

    }
  }
});
```

Нужно взять количество li.
Как я только не пытался это сделать, но результат всегда length = 0 Если просто написать список из нескольких li,то всё работает, а если использовать директиву для вывода, то результат равен 0.

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>картинка</li>
    <li>картинка</li>
    <li>картинка</li>
    <li>картинка</li>
    <li>картинка</li>
  </ul>
  <span>кружок</span>
  <span>кружок</span>
  <span>кружок</span>
  <span>кружок</span>
  <span>кружок</span>
</div>
```

Comment: количество li равно `images.length`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но это мне не поможет
я смогу взять так только в вызове метода .then() после того как получу данные с сервера, а мне нужно получить количество li, чтобы использовать в директиве

Comment: абсолютно ничего не понятно. что именно ты хочешь сделать. Добавляй сюда пример твоего кода, и описание **что именно** ты хочешь сделать. Более того: количество _li равно images.length_ поэтому если _images.length_ - 0. то и количество  - 0, если _images.length_ присвоили значение в then, то и li добавились. Нельзя посчитать количество li, до того, как определится значение images.length.

Comment: Беру данные с сервера
[photo](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20161123-17cj-7kb.jpg)
Потом в директиве 
[photo](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20161123-stxj-18kb.jpg)
хочу сделать слайдер, но для этого мне нужно количество элементов

Comment: Весь необходимый код должен быть **непосредственно** в вопросе. Причем должен быть кодом, а не картинками.

Comment: сейчас всё сделаю

Comment: А где именно ты пытался _брать количество li_? И все еще непонятно **зачем** понадобилось именно количество `li`?

Comment: я пытался взять в директиве в link функции
количество нужно для того чтобы сделать слайдер, чтобы генерировать количество кружков, по которым я буду кликать и слайдер будет двигаться, сколько li столько и кружков
Если есть вариант лучше это реализовать, расскажите, буду благодарен:)

Comment: какая итоговая разметка должна была получиться вместе с кружками? Проще всего добавить их генерацию прямо в шаблон

Comment: кружки должны быть внизу слайдера, относительно блока, в котором находится ul

Comment: Добавь пример с конечной разметкой, которая должна получиться

Comment: <div class="slider">
 <ul>
  <li>картинка</li>
  <li>картинка</li>
  <li>картинка</li>
  <li>картинка</li>
  <li>картинка</li>
 </ul>
 <span>кружок</span>
 <span>кружок</span>
 <span>кружок</span>
 <span>кружок</span>
 <span>кружок</span>
</div>

Comment: не, не. не :-) сам видишь - в комментариях код ужасно смотрится и ничего не понятно: добавляй в сам вопрос это

Comment: хорошо, добавил

Comment: а сама директива _sliderShow_ где располагается? вот на этом диве? `<div class="slider">`

Comment: да, на этом диве

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае проблема решается редактированием шаблона. Круги тоже должны рисоваться с помощью `ng-repeat`.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("MainController", ['$scope', '$timeout',
  function MainController($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    }, 2000);

  }
]);

angular.module('app').directive('sliderShow', function sliderShow() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: "<ul id='ul'><li ng-repeat='img in images'>картинка{{$index}}</li></ul><span ng-repeat='img in images'>кружок{{$index}}</span>",
    link: function link(scope, element, attr) {

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div slider-show>Loading...</div>
</div>
```